Make backslash \ in terminal (Danish keyboard)
I am using a Danish keyboard language and Danish keyboard layout. When typing in my browser or other applications on my computer, I can make a backslash. In my case I use the combination shift + option + /. However, when I enter the terminal (either through VSC or directly from my computer), I can't make backslash through the key combination. Nothing happens. I am using bash.
I have also tried the Z shell instead, but I can't make backslash there as well. For similar characters I can use their key combinations without any problems in the bash terminal. E.g. shift + option + ( makes an opening curly bracket '{'.
Thus, the key combination for backslash works fine in browser and applications, but not in the terminal. Is there a way to add a new key combination for the terminal?

@user1934428 Correct. In pages, browser, textedit, or any other applications I have tried, I can make backslash. However, a slight update on the terminal.app (which makes it more weird): when I open terminal.app I can make backslash now. However, if I open a new terminal window from within the terminal.app, I suddenly can't make backslash. And also when I access terminal through VSC (the editor I use), I also can't make backslash.

Out of curiousity: How do you open a new terminal window from within  terminal app, and what's the point in doing so?

If you have set your terminal to treat the "option" key as "meta" key, it will send ESC(0x1b, \e)-prefixed ASCII sequences to the shell instead of going through keylayout translations. E.g. option+a becomes ESC a. In macOS preinstalled Terminal.app you can toggle this preference with a menu bar item called "Use Option as Meta key". I don't know if a similar toggle exist in VSCode's xterm.js. If you want to insert \ without disabling option-as-meta, you can set a key sequence binding in your shell to insert "\" when received ESC /. I don't have a mac with me to verify my answer, but it should work.

Below is an image of a Danish Magic Keyboard with Touch ID and Numeric Keypad for Mac models with Apple silicon.

Under the Terminal Application preferences, you can set ⇧ (shift)+option+/ to produce the \ character, where / is the key on the numeric keypad shown above. See image below.

You may choose a difference key and modifier, if you wish.
If you do not have a numeric keypad, then see below.
Below is an image of a Danish Magic Keyboard with Touch ID for Mac models with Apple silicon.

Under the Terminal Application preferences, you can set ⇧ (shift)+fn+F4 to produce the \ character. See image below.

You may choose a difference key and modifier, if you wish.
